# How to prevent react native WebView from cache?

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm using react native webview for my project. The content is an HTML file that is located in the assets folder. The problem is that whenever I change inside the html file for instance I change the css or javascript and save it, the webview doesn't change and shows the previous html file. To solve this issue I should stop the project and start it again in order to see my changes (I have to use npm start). I've used all tricks such as:

- incognito ={true}
- cacheEnabled={false}
- cacheMode='LOAD_NO_CACHE'

but neither of them is useful. What should I do ??
My code is :

```
const Home = () => {
  const mainUrl = 'file:///android_asset/map.html'
  const webView = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0)
  useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(value)
  },[value])

  const onMessage =(event)=>{
      var data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
      if (data.key == 'refresh') {
       
          webView.current?.reload()
          //webView.current?.clearCache(true)
          setValue(value + 1);
      }
  }

  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        ref={webView}
        key= "comp1"
        incognito ={true}
        cacheEnabled={false}
        cacheMode='LOAD_NO_CACHE'
        source={{ uri: mainUrl + `?var=${value}` }}
        onMessage={onMessage}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        allowFileAccess={true}
        allowingReadAccessToURL={'file:///'}
        style={styles.map}
      />
     
    </View>

  )
}

export default Home
```